# Event receiver feature update

Tags: feature, event-handlers, feature-activation, feature-upgrade

I am developing an event receiver in VS2010. To test the event receiver I deploy it to development using the functionality within VS 2010. This works without problems.

However my concerns start when I deploy the feature to production. I activate the event receiver on the sites I want it to be activated. Now I want to make some changes to the event receiver, and basically update the deployed event receiver afterwards on production (say version 2.0).

What will happen now? Will the event receiver (Feature) still be activated on the subsites where I activated version 1, and if it is activated should the event receiver still work ?

When I'm testing in VS2010 this does not work. The feature is still activated on the subsites, but the event is not firing anymore. How can I disable and enable the feature manually again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this tool](http://spfeatureupgrade.codeplex.com/). This tool is useful if you would like to update existed feature.

Comment: Answers my question :)